# Given a topological field with non-trivial topology given by a metric, is the metric necessarily translation-invariant?

Tags: fields, metric-spaces

If the topology is locally compact and non-trivial, then the metric is usually translation-invariant or even arises from a norm. But is it necessary to be invariant? I failed to give a counterexample.

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}$, you can take e.g. $d(x,y):=|f(x) - f(y)|$ for any monotone homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Take $\mathbb R$ with any metric quasi-isometric to the standard one.

Comment: It may be worth noting that one can also construct non-standard *uniform* structures on $\mathbb{R}$ that induce the standard topology, e.g. by using my construction with $f$ bounded.